# How do I change a .gif file to a .png file after a couple of seconds using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have this line of HTML in my code:

```
<img src="https://mundonewimpact.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/MNI-Logo-3.png" id="site-logo" alt="Mundo New Impact">
```

and what I want to do is that, everytime an user loads any page from my website, this img loads a .gif file (which is: https://im3.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-3-d8b13ba46bfb.gif) for a couple of seconds, enough for its animation to finish, and then replace this .gif file to the original .png file.

I tried using this piece of javascript code, but it doesn't work:

```
function play(){
  var img = document.getElementById("site-logo");
  if (img.src = "https://mundonewimpact.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/MNI-Logo-3.png"){
    img.src = "https://im3.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-3-d8b13ba46bfb.gif";
  }else{
    img.src = "https://mundonewimpact.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/MNI-Logo-3.png"; 
  }
  setTimeout(function(){end()},10000);
}

function end(){
  document.getElementById("site-logo").src = "https://mundonewimpact.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/MNI-Logo-3.png";
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I am a total noob so help me please!

Comment: Hey, did you call `play` somewhere?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: I am working on this website: https://mundonewimpact.com.br/. The <img> is the one that appears on the header. They want it to have an animation every time the page loads, which is the .gif file.

Comment: @AlexHidanBR Besides the fact that I [highly advise against running an animation like this on page load](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/69974/89451), it may be a cleaner solution to [make the .gif itself loop once](https://ezgif.com/loop-count). This way, it's dependency-free.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `play()`in order to run the function.

You also have mistakes like `if (img.src = ...` instead of `if (img.src == ...`.

I would work with event handlers, like, show the GIF animation and when the document ready event triggers, change the GIF to a different image.

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    var img = document.getElementById("site-logo");
    img.src = "https://mundonewimpact.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/MNI-Logo-3.png";
});
</script>
```

Comment: I tried to type:

    var img = document.getElementById("site-logo").play();

But it didn't work either.

Comment: Dude, this is the most basic JavaScript that can happen. How do I show you... `<script>play();</script>` would work. But your whole script is not the best...

Comment: How can I make my script better?

Comment: I like the idea of using an event handler, but I am afraid that the page loads so fast that the gif doesn't properly finish its animation.

Comment: So you want to manually slow down the website? lmao https://thedailywtf.com/articles/The-Slow-Down-Loop

Comment: No, that's not it. What I want is like... when the page loads, it first loads the .gif, then after the gif completes its animation, it loads the png. The purpose of this script is so the website's logo shows an animation but only once,

Comment: @AlexHidanBR On Stackoverflow typically people won't code all the stuff for you, just give you hints and help you with specific things. That's what I did. I showed you few mistakes in your script and suggested to use event handlers.

Comment: Ok, I am sorry.